# Is there a way to replace "2020-09-06 12:00:00": [...] By "timestamp": "2019-12-18T10:30:00Z", "keys": [ In Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection:

```
{
    "2020-09-06 12:00:00": [
        {
            "usage_point_id": "12345678912345",        
            "key": "0.7680189"
        },
        {
            "usage_point_id": "12345678912346",        
            "key": "0.29539188"
        },
    ]
}
```

I would like to transform it to:

```
[{    
    "timestamp": "2019-12-18T10:30:00Z",
    "keys": [      
        {        
            "usage_point_id": "12345678912345",        
            "key": "12,5"      
        },
        {
            "usage_point_id": "12345678912346",        
            "key": "0.29539188"
        },
    ]   
}]
```

They question is how to change:

```
    "2020-09-06 12:00:00": [
```

with

```
    "timestamp": "2019-12-18T10:30:00Z",
```

I get this collection with the query:

```
 $measures = Measure::where('operation_id', $operation->name)
            ->whereBetween('time', [$from, $to])
            ->select(['time AS timestamp', 'meter_id AS usage_point_id', 'repartition_rate AS key'])
            ->get()->groupBy('timestamp');
```

is there a special helper for collections for that purpose ?

Comment: What's the logic behind changing the date from `2020-09-06` to `2019-12-18` ?! Subtract 263 days?

Comment: changed $key => [...] with "timestamp" => $key, [...]

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? How do you actually get to the stage where you want to transform the collection?

Comment: yep, no problem, I get it by a groupBy on a collection

Comment: added query in question @Dan

Comment: Your desired collection result looks like one result to me wheras the one you get from the query can actually return multiple.

Comment: both have several timestamps, and in each timestamp several keys ( 1 key per usage_point_id)

Comment: I fixed it surrounding desired result with [...] in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to your problem would be to map through all entries and modify their contents:

```
$measures
    ->map(function ($item, $key) {
        return [
            "timestamp" => Carbon\Carbon::make($key)->toISOString(),
            "keys" => $item,
        ];
    })
    ->values();
```

In Juliatzin case it constantly overwrites the key so it only returns the last entry if you have multiple entries from your database result.

Comment: this is not working, i still have: "2020-09-06 12:00:00": {} wrapping the timestamps and keys.

Comment: That's weird. Here's the example I've been working with: https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/7f717ec6-8660-4340-aaf7-8cd1f6fca187

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the ->values() method. Yep, I think your method is simpler than mine !

Comment: But I have no need to reformat the timestamp with Carbon !

Comment: Glad I could help. I transformed the timestamp with Carbon since it's the easiest method to match your example.

Comment: Lol, I didn't noticed there were a difference of format ! Nice catch !

Comment: but toISOString() is not the good one, because it is getting nanoseconds

Comment: You're right. Does `toIso8601ZuluString()` fit your needs better?

Comment: Yep, totally ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, with [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys)

```
$measures = $measures->mapWithKeys(function ($measure, $key) {
            return [
                'timestamp' => $key,
                'keys' => $measure
            ];
        });
```

Comment: For the date you can use `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($key)->toIso8601ZuluString(),`